# Force password expiration multiple-users one-time

Tags: linux, shadow, multiple-users, passwd

How can I query all users on a box and force password expiration?

Currently, I am querying all users:

```
getent shadow | awk -F: '$2 ~ /^\$/ || $2 ~ /^!\$/ {print $1} {print $3}'
```

And this gets me the user name as well as the last password change, but I only need to force the `passwd -e` on users who haven't changed their password since before March 1, 2022 - anyone who has changed their password after March 1, 2022 I can leave those alone (I believe this would be a value of 19052 - so any value greater than or equal to that I can skip).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the approach @KamilCuk took. To add to that I would include a minimum `UID` and maximum `UID` on parsing `/etc/passwd` to exclude system accounts. (note: some distributions start the first non-system UID at differing values, usually either `500` or `1000` -- check your distro). The maximum `UID` can exclude generic user accounts placed at the top of the range like the `nobody` account on openSUSE with `UID == 65534`

To determine whether to expire an account with a password change older that March 1, 2022, it is fairly easy to convert that date and the date returned by `chage` to seconds-since-Epoch. That way you can use a simple comparison of if the last password change is less than the number of seconds since Epoch for March 1, 2022 -- expire the account.

Below is one approach you can take to put it all together. `xargs` is another option to build the list instead of expiring accounts one-by-one. The actual expiration is commented out below and instead the command that would be run is printed to `stdout` to allow testing before actual expiration of accounts.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

## validate script is run with root privilege
[ $UID != 0 ] && [ $EUID != 0 ] && {
  printf "error: script must be run as root, UID '%s' can't,\n" "$UID" >&2
  exit 1
} 

minUID=1000     ## first non-system UID
maxUID=65534    ## nobody

march1epoch=$(date -d "2022-03-01" +%s)   ## seconds since epoch

## pipe non-system users to while loop to check aging with chage
awk -v minU="$minUID" -v maxU="$maxUID" -F: '
  $3 >= minU && $3 < maxU { print $1 }
' /etc/passwd | 
{
## read each user name, get age since last pw change
while read -r usrnm; do 
  age=$(date -d "$(chage -l "$usrnm" | 
        awk -F: 'FNR==1 {print $NF; exit}')" +%s)
  ## compare with march1epoch, expire all that are older
  [ "$age" -lt "$march1epoch" ] && echo "passwd -e \"$usrnm\""
  ### uncomment line below to actually expire account
  # [ "$age" -lt "$march1epoch" ] && passwd -e "$usrnm"
done
}
```

(**note:** you can use *Process Substitution* to feed the `while` loop in bash rather than piping the results to it -- up to you. If you are stuck with POSIX shell, then piping will work in both instances)

When satisfied, uncomment the final line in the loop, and optionally remove the line that simply outputs the command that would be run.

Comment: This works wonderfully. I had to modify it slightly to exclude some super user accounts that run functions on the machine (third party applications), but this helped immensely. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I did this:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | { while IFS= read -r n; do echo -n "$n "; chage -li "$n" | awk 'NR==1{print $NF}'; done; echo CUTME 2022-03-01; } | sort -k2 | awk 'f{print} /CUTME/{f=1}'
```

You can then `xargs passwd -e` if you want.

Comment: I like it. I'd probably add a min/max UID on the `/etc/passwd` accounts to ignore system accounts. Instead of `cut`, maybe something like `awk -F: '$3>=1000 && $3 <65534 {print $1}' /etc/passwd` (adjust the min UID as needed, some distros use 500, the max is `nobody`) You can get seconds since Epoch for aging use with something like `date -d "$(awk -F: 'FNR==1 {print $NF; exit}')" +%s`